# Read and Write a Very big text file using openmp

Tags: io, openmp

I have a very big text file (grater than 90 GB) I have to read the file, I have tried to read the same sequentially but as expected it is taking a lot of time. If I use openmp to do the same, is that feasible? I am pretty new to openmp.

Comment: Reading from disk is best done sequentally, but to process the data it is woth using OpenMP.

Comment: https://cpufun.substack.com/p/processing-a-file-with-openmp may help, though it's unclear from your question whether you read the file to build a single data structure that you then process, or can prices parts of the files as soon as you have read them. That makes a big difference!

Comment: @JimCownie Thank you so much for your answer. I want to read the file using OpenMP create a data structure and do some processing on that data structure(In a GPU) and then write the processed data to a output file using OpenMP.